# Simulate 'grass' using a replicator

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, motion

In Apple Motion I thought I'd be able to use a replicator to simulate grass using 'Randomize' on the element angle and then duplicating the individual 'blade' elements using a replicator with 'random fill'.

[image: desired look]

Unfortunately, every element ends up with identical movement - the randomize behaviour globally affects all the replicated elements, so I end up with something like this.

[image]

Is there a way to individually randomize the motion of replicated elements?

Comment: I suggest you add some tags to this question and tell us what program you are working with.

Comment: I tagged it Motion! I'll see if there's an "Apple Motion" tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through all the library replicators and found one that used a Randomize behaviour on the cell's `Object.Angle Randomness.Angle Randomness`. This looks okay. Everything is still kinda moving in sync if you look carefully but things go to different angles more naturally. I think overlaying a couple of these will look about right for my purposes. But I'd still rather each replicated element had parameters of its own.